# How to remove bottom navigation and tool bar using "addOnDestinationChangedListener"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, toolbar, bottomnavigationview

I am working on an application which requires login and/or sign up. I am also using a custom toolbar and bottom navigation bar and I wanted to remove these from **login** and **create account** fragments. I was successfully able to remove them from login fragment by using the code below for tool bar:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            toolbar.visibility = if (destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
                View.GONE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

and a similar code for bottom navigation:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = if (destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
                View.GONE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

What I want to know is that like I hid the tool bar from login fragment. How can I also remove it from another fragment?

MainActivity.KT:

```
package com.example.integratedmodulateoroperationroom

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.*
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.loginFragment),
            drawer_layout
        )

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            toolbar.visibility = if (destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
                View.GONE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)
        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            bottomNavigationView.visibility = if (destination.id == R.id.loginFragment) {
                View.GONE
            } else {
                View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

activity_main.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: "But the problem here is that although I removed them from login screen, they still popped up in create account fragment" - well yeah, your code says if you aren't on the login screen, the the visibility should be `View.VISIBLE`. Is there a reason you aren't just changing that code to take into account both destinations you want it to be `View.GONE` in?

Comment: That's what I am asking how to add more fragments non-visible. I tried to reuse the code for the fragment but it didnt worked. I am not from a coding background so I might be missing a trick here. Been trying different solutions for 4 days to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after experimenting with a lot of stuff I got a solution... there wasn't much to be done a little changing in the code and it worked.
For toolbar:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                else -> toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```

Similarly, for bottom navigation view we use :

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.loginFragment, R.id.createAccountFragment ->
                    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                else -> bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
```